# .htaccess to allow .html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, directory

so I have it rewriting .html to .php, but then it won't load .html files when I need it to. Is there a way to get it to ignore the bookstore directory? I thought I have that in there already, but it doesn't work.

```
/public_html/.htaccess
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/bookstore/"
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://virtualbookworm.com/$1.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

../bookstore/.htaccess
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options +Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore the bookstore directory, you need a `!` in front of the expression:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/bookstore/
```

Or, you can just turn on the rewrite engine in the htaccess file in the `bookstore` directory and the rules in your document root will be superceded:

```
../bookstore/.htaccess
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options +Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
RewriteEngine On
```

Additionally, the inclusion of the `http://virtualbookworm.com` in the rule's target will cause the browser to be redirected (using a 302 response) and it'll change the URL in the address bar. If that's not what you want, just remove it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/bookstore/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://virtualbookworm.com/$1.php [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should filter requests out, so that the rule is only applied if the 'requested' file does not exist.

Comment: of note, the `!-f` tells mod_rewrite to ignore any files which actually exist and exclude them from rewriting.